# Adding JSON Object

Tags: javascript

Current JSON Object is

```
{
 "firstName":"fname",
 "lastName":"lname",
 "department": {
    "department":"d1",
    "location":"l1" 
  }
}
```

I want to add one more array into it like below using Javascript:

```
{
  "firstName":"fname",
  "lastName":"lname",
  "department": {
  "department":"d1",
  "location":"l1"
 },
  "address": {
    "street1":"s1",
    "street2":s2
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you checkout [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for future endeavor at Stack overflow.Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community  -Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can do this by simple way

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>    
    
    <div id="myid"></div>

    <script id='script' type='text/javascript'>

        var myjson1 = {
            "firstName": "fname",
            "lastName": "lname",
            "department":
                {
                    "department": "d1",
                    "location": "l1"
                }
        }

        var myjson2 = {
            "address":
                {
                    "street1": "s1",
                    "street2": "s2"
                }
        }


        myjson1.address = myjson2;

        document.getElementById("myid").innerText = JSON.stringify(myjson1);

        console.log(myjson1);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:**

If you have two json object
for example:

```
var myjson1 = {
            "firstName": "fname",
            "lastName": "lname",
            "department":
                {
                    "department": "d1",
                    "location": "l1"
                }
        }
```

and

```
var myjson2 = {
            "firstName": "fname",
            "lastName": "lname",
            "department":
                {
                    "department": "d1",
                    "location": "l1"
                }
        }
```

If you want to perform equal condition on both above json object's key like "firstName" and "lastName" and then wanted to add new json after equal condition satisfied.
for example

```
var myjson3 = {
                "address":
                    {
                        "street1": "s1",
                        "street2": "s2"
                    }
            }
```

then you have to compare both json object's keys like

```
 if (myjson1.firstName == myjson2.firstName && myjson1.lastName == myjson2.lastName) {
            console.log('matched');

            myjson1.address = myjson3;

            //OR

            myjson2.address = myjson3;
        }
```

Comment: what if myjson1 and myjson2 both have firstName and lastName and I need to check if both are same then only "myjson1.address = myjson2;" should execute.

Comment: @Apurb Kumar Choudhary, I added an example for you, so please check edit section in answer.and let me know whether its help you or not

Comment: @Apurb Kumar Choudhary, Please let me know if the edited section of answer help you or not if yes then "accept" answer :)

Comment: @Apurb Kumar Choudhary, I m glad to see my answer was helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

In JS, this is easy!

```js
var a = {
"firstName":"fname",
"lastName":"lname",
"department":
{
"department":"d1",
"location":"l1"}
};

a.address = {
"street1":"s1",
"street2":s2
};
```

Comment: If my answer was satisfactory, would you be so kind as to 'accept' it as the correct answer?